# VBA Collection or Dictionary with an array and key

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following data:
ID | Company | RDate

I want to create a dictionary or collection with the ID as key and (Company, RDate) as the value.

The error I am receiving is that I have a type-mismatch on the line where I try to add the key and tuple to the collection.

Ideal structure:
ID, (Company, RDate)

Key, (Value A, Value B)

Below is my attempt:

Demo code

```
Dim ID              As String
Dim Company         As String
Dim RDate           As Date

Dim myCol           As Collection

Set myCol = New Collection
myCol.Add Array(Company, RDate), ID

Dim myVar           As Variant

For Each myVar In myCol.Keys        'this is just code to test that I successfully added the data to the collection
    
    Debug.Print myCol(myVar)(LBound(myCol(myVar)))
    
Next myVar
```

Comment: `key Optional. A unique string expression that specifies a key` but `Dim ID As Long`

Comment: Thank you, I changed ID to a string and still have a type mismatch error. I will change my above code to reflect that change.

Comment: I cannot understand too much from your question... You firstly posted a strange piece of code declaring a variable `As String` and mentioning in a comment that it is an array... Now you show another code. A collection does not have a `keys` property. Do you want using a dictionary?

Comment: You can add items with a key in collections: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/add-method-visual-basic-for-applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried mixing a collection with a dictionary... Please, test the next adapted  code which uses a dictionary and test it as in your code:

```
Sub testCollDictionary()
 Dim ID As String, Company As String, RDate As Date, myCol As Object

 RDate = Date: ID = "1234": Company = "MyConpany"

 Set myCol = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
 myCol.Add ID, Array(Company, RDate)

 Dim myVar  As Variant

 For Each myVar In myCol.Keys 'this is just code to test that I successfully added the data to the DICTIONARY..
    
    Debug.Print myCol(myVar)(LBound(myCol(myVar)))
    
 Next myVar
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

### Dictionary vs Collection

**The Question**

- You could have used the following in your question to make things clearer.

```vb
Sub Question()
    
    Dim ID As Long: ID = 1
    Dim Company As String: Company = "Querty"
    Dim RDate As Date: RDate = Date
    
    Dim myCol As Collection: Set myCol = New Collection
    myCol.Add Array(Company, RDate), ID ' Run-time error '13': Type mismatch
    
    Dim myVar  As Variant
    For Each myVar In myCol.Keys
        Debug.Print myCol(myVar)(LBound(myCol(myVar)))
    Next myVar

End Sub
```

**Collection**

- The following illustrates the key limitation of the collection (for this case).

```vb
Sub Answer()
    
    Dim ID As String: ID = "1"
    Dim Company As String: Company = "Querty"
    Dim RDate As Date: RDate = Date
    
    Dim myCol As Collection: Set myCol = New Collection
    myCol.Add VBA.Array(Company, RDate), ID ' ensure zero-based with 'VBA.'
    
    Dim myVar As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    For Each myVar In myCol
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print "In the Loop", myVar(0), myVar(1), i
    Next myVar

    ' You cannot get the key,
    
    ' ... but you can get the data using the key...
    Dim myKey As String: myKey = ID
    On Error Resume Next
        Debug.Print "Use the Key", myCol(myKey)(0), myCol(myKey)(1)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' ... or you can use the index.
    Debug.Print "Use the Index", myCol(1)(0), myCol(1)(1), 1

    ' Conclusion
    ' Use the dictionary instead.

End Sub
```

**Dictionary**

- The following illustrates how easy it is by using the dictionary.

```vb
Sub Dictionary()
    
    Dim ID As Long: ID = 1
    Dim Company As String: Company = "Querty"
    Dim RDate As Date: RDate = Date
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    dict(ID) = VBA.Array(Company, RDate) ' ensure zero-based with 'VBA.'
    
    Dim myKey As Variant
    For Each myKey In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print myKey, dict(myKey)(0), dict(myKey)(1)
    Next myKey

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Store an array as the value:

```vb
Dim Id              As String
Dim Company         As String
Dim RDate           As Date
Dim Index           As Integer

Dim myCol           As Collection

Set myCol = New Collection

Id = CStr(1)
Company = "Corp. A"
RDate = Date
myCol.Add Array(Company, RDate), Id

Id = CStr(2)
Company = "Corp. B"
RDate = Date
myCol.Add Array(Company, RDate), Id

For Index = 1 To myCol.Count
    Debug.Print Index, myCol(Index)(0), myCol(Index)(1)
Next

Set myCol = Nothing
```

Output:

```
 1            Corp. A       20-09-2022 
 2            Corp. B       20-09-2022
```